# Slow internet using Arch Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, connection

After a week or so of using Arch Linux I cant access the Internet. It takes around 5 mins to load Google (most of the other websites just give me a timeout), pacman’s downloading speed range between 5-2Kbs, and pinging google takes around 9Kms.

I’m connected using wireless network (Wi-Fi card is Intel Ultimate 6300 and router is Edimax 6524n).

Every other Windows machine that's connected to the network (and even the T410 running Windows) is fine, so the problem lies in Linux.

So far, i checked the `resolv.conf` file (my router IP address is listed), and the hosts file (pretty much default), and I disabled the IPv6 module.

None of that helped.

I'm using NetworkManager (but the problem still occurs when connecting using wicd) running on Gnome3.

Also, something really strange happens whenever I ping Google: I get an unknown host 'google.com', but the bit rate from the card jumps at the exact second I ping google (so far, the bit rate jumped to 54Mb/s from 1Mb/s over the course of 4 pings).

Comment: please be specific: 1. Did it work before? If yes, what did you do? There is the file `/var/log/pacman.log`, which lists all your install/uninstall operations. Browse it. 2. The file `/etc/resolve.conf` should contain at least one nameserver with an ip. Try to ping this ip, what's the response?

Comment: Please post the output of `dmesg | grep -i iwlagn`.

Comment: @Sebastian 1. It did work before, but I had to reinstall Arch. 2. The /etc/resolve.conf lists my router IP, which acts as my DNS server.

Comment: @Patches http://pastebin.com/Pmhi6swv

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to try:

- Ping the IP directly (i.e. `ping 8.8.8.8`). Is the responses quicker? If yes, it's probably a DNS issue.
- Connect via an Ethernet cord (Wired). If the response is quicker you might have a driver issue or some software issue concerning your wireless card.
- Run `wireshark` and then ping. Is your ICMP package sent at all? This will display some wireless network issues.
- Run `strace ping 8.8.8.8`, by looking over the output you'll be able to determine some software issues (like, not being able to bind to a socket).

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure you did set your Host Name in `/etc/rc.conf` and also in `/etc/hosts` to the same name? I.e., edit `/etc/hosts` and add the same `HOSTNAME` as you entered in `/etc/rc.conf`.

This is usually the cause of lack of network connectivity :)